# How to configure persistent routes?

Tags: routing, lan

In my company I have a LAN 192.168.100.0/24. My desktop PC at work has an IP address 192.168.100.100 and LogMeIn IP 25.50.70.30. Only from inside that LAN I can access my server located at 192.168.101.20 in a subnet 192.168.101.0/24.

From my house via internet I use a laptop with LogMeIn Hamachi to connect to my desktop in a company. The laptop has LogMeIn IP 25.50.60.30.

What command I have to use to add persistent rout in the laptop, that I can ping and RDP from the laptop from my home to the server at work?

Comment: Configuration of end-devices like PCs is off-topic here, as are questions about home networking and networks over which you have no control. You need to work with your network administrators at work to figure this out.

Comment: LogMeIn isn't a VPN tunnel. It connects you to a single node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  you can't.

Your desktop PC is behind a firewall which both prevents external devices (like your home PC) from initiating connections to internal devices andalso provides network address translation (NAT) where the internal IP 192. 168.100.100 gets translated to a public address.   This translation is temporary -- it only lasts as long as the PC is connecting to external devices.

These firewall features are put in place to protect the organization from external attacks  What you are asking to do is defeat these protections, which puts your organization at risk from Internet attacks.

Logmein acts as an intermediary -- your desktop PC connects to it, and so does your home PC.  Logmein then bridges the two connections together so you can control your desktop from home.

If you need remote access to your PC or server, ask your administrator if VPN access is possible.  If not, Logmein is the next best thing, assuming your compnay approves of what you're doing.